# Git commit asks for passphrase which I don't remember

Tags: git, github, gitlab, github-for-windows, git-repo

Few days ago, I created a GPG key in my GitLab account. Now I was trying to commit a new project into my GitHub account, I get a pop-up window asking to enter a passphrase to unlock the OpenPGP secret key. Unfortunately, I don't remember the passphrase. I tried to revoke the passphrase or change the passphrase, but it still asks me to enter the passphrase.
I want to commit the project to my GitHub account, which I couldn't because of the passphrase, what should I do now? I am using Windows 10 OS. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"I tried to revoke the passphrase or change the passphrase, but it still asks me to enter the passphrase. "* - you gotta remove the key from local git's key store too..

Comment: Thanks @BagusTesa for your help. This command `git config commit.gpgsign false` worked for me. Thanks :)